# Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 401 in axios call and Cookies has been rejected because a non HTTP key can't be secure"

Tags: reactjs, axios, http-status-code-400

I am trying to fetch some data using axios GET request
How do i resolve it? This works on someone else's computer but it does'nt work on mine. The api docs, urls api config everything is alright. It just does'nt work on my computer. I have tried different browsers too others facing the same problem switched the browser from chrome to firefox and it worked but it does'nt in my case.
It shows 401 and "Cookies has been rejected because a non HTTP key can't be secure"

```
const [courseId, setCourseId]
const getAllcourse = () => {
        axios
            .get(`${appConfig.host}${urls.getSpecificCourse}?courseId=${courseId}`)
            .then((success) => {
                console.log("Get all courses", success.data);
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.log(error);
            });
    };
```

Comment: this strongly depends of the API docs and your `appConfig.host` and `urls.getAllcourses` variables. please provide more information.

Comment: @JorgeKunrath Just edited my question.

Comment: Are you accessing it with `https://` or `http://`? I mean, both API and your browser's navbar